# How to run a powershell script with different credentials

Tags: powershell

I need to run a powershell script (In remote server) with different username and password.

I need to pass the credentials in a single command line. Could someone please give me the command

```
scriptname: configure.ps1
username: xyz
password: pwd123
```

Answer (score 0):

I am actully trying to connect the windows server from Ansible control Linux server. I followed all the steps which you have suggested in my playbook.

Case1: Tried with my own username and password, I am able to run the powershell script in windows machine

Case2: Tried with the technical account, I am getting error. Error details pasted below.

```
fatal: [linux_server]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "$password = \"password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force\n $username = \"admin\\username\"\n $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)\n cd D:\\Risk_AppServer\\test\\\n Invoke-Command -ComputerName windows_server -FilePath .\\sample_ps1.ps1 -credential $credential", "delta": "0:00:00.843081", "end": "2018-09-19 06:31:56.239923", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-09-19 06:31:55.396841", "stderr": "[windows_server] Connecting to remote server windows_server failed with the following error message : Acce\r\nss is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (windows_server:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken", "stderr_lines": ["[windows_server] Connecting t**o remote server windows_server failed with the following error message : Acce", "ss is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.", "    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (windows_server:String) [**], PSRemotingTransportException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Please NOTE: With Technical account username and password I am able to login the windows machine successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite the same thing, but stops you having to have new code:  you could run the script as a scheduled task, with the task running as the user account you want to use.

Open Task Scheduler, click 'Create Task' and add the name and a meaningful description of the task on the 'General' tab.

Set Security Options.

On the 'Triggers' tab, click 'New' and set the timing as required:

On the 'Actions' tab, click 'New', and under 'Program/script' use the following syntax to run PowerShell and call the script:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&{<path2script>.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE}"
```

Hit Yes at the prompt you get about arguments.